# Git merge two diferents histories

Tags: git

I'm importing an old CVS repository from sourceforge (mmorpg made in visual basic 6 http://www.argentumonline.org), and we continue the work without importing the history before.

So now I have a git repository with all the CVS history
https://github.com/RecoX/cvs2gitao

The current project: https://github.com/ao-libre/ao-cliente

How can I add the CVS History to the bottom of the current repository?

I'm trying to do this solution as I got just a `master` branch did this.

Inside my current repository

```
git remote add morgoao git@github.com:RecoX/cvs2gitao.git
git fetch morgoao
git rebase morgoao/master
```

and got a lot of Merge Conflicts the message said:

```
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".

You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".

To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

I use `git rebase --skip` but is not working, what should I do ?

Comment: How many main branches? If it's just master, rebase one onto the other.

Comment: It's just master so I'm trying to do a rebase now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the current repository where I am working I make this work:|

```
git remote add morgoao git@github.com:RecoX/cvs2gitao.git
git fetch morgoao
git rebase -X theirs morgoao/master
```

Just note that in rebase `theirs` is the opposite that you think, is the current branch where are you step at the moment.

And it works like a charm :)

For more information I wrote a tutorial:
https://medium.com/@requitolucas/importar-repositorio-cvs-a-git-sourceforge-a-github-de-manera-facil-20c63344bfa5

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the original CVS repo, it contains only a `master` branch. It also looks like you've already absorbed it into the modern repository as `mergecvs`.  I am assuming that in the new repo, `master` and `mergecvs` don't share any commits. That makes it possible to do

```
git checkout master
git rebase mergecvs
```

And that's it. I might also turn `mergecvs` into a tag since it's going nowhere, but you probably want to keep the tip of it marked in history.

Since the updated `master` branch will be a complete rewrite, you will want to rebase the other branches you have onto the corresponding locations in the new history. This should, in theory, cause no conflicts either.

Comment: I'm trying to do this solution so I made this. 

Inside my current repository
```
git remote add morgoao git@github.com:RecoX/cvs2gitao.git
get fetch morgoao
git rebase morgoao/master
```

and got a lot of Merge Conflicts the message said:

```
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```
I use `git rebase --skip` but is not working, what should I do ?

Comment: You should resolve all the conflicts. Don't just mark them as resolved.